# Website asking for authentication

Tags: php, authentication

My website asking for authentication when I go to the website url. It says that

```
"A username and password are being requested by http://test.com. The site says: "c100 Undetectable #18a: Restricted area"
```

When I click on cancel buton then it will disappear. It will ask every time when I refresh the page or click on a link.. What can I do for removing this???

Comment: Remove the headers requesting authentication?

Comment: if it is your own website check for any code thats asking for that? or an .htaccess entry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please check for this code in your all pages and there are some headers for this authentication as below :-

```
if($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]  && $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"]){

}        
header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=);
header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
```

Please remove this and your problem will be solved.
To Learn more about authentication please see - [link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)